# REST API slow response on production server

Tags: rest, nginx, server

I have a spring-boot application that uses Java on the backend and react.js on the frontend side. Some API calls are too slow in the production environment (it takes 1 min in the production environment and 4 ms in the local). The slow APIs are not fetching any large data set. I was trying to debug the code and found Nginx error logs. The logs are as follows:

> [error] 29755#29755: *632803 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.XX.X.XX, server: test.apps.com, request: "GET /apiv1/master/modules?&isglobal=all&startIndex=0&pageSize=10&sortBy=id HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://172.XX.X.XX:443/mhk-cmt-app/master/modules?&isglobal=all&startIndex=0&pageSize=10&sortBy=id", host: "test.apps.com", referrer: "https://test.apps.com/admin/app-setting"

How can I improve the API response time in production?

Comment: Unless getting to know more details it's just speculation. Maybe nginx or the upstream is running or of CPU or there might be network issues causing connection drops. or maybe there is some misconfiguration causing different behavior between local & production.